# LocalTime to server timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetimepicker

I don't know what timezone my server is in and I recently learned about ISO 8601 and I'm getting my date in this format from backend:

```
2017-01-21T00:32:59Z
```

**Question #1:**

when I do

```
var date = new Date("2017-01-21T00:32:59Z");
console.log(date); //It displays date in local PST format.
Fri Jan 20 2017 16:32:59 GMT-0800 (PST) //Not what I'm expecting
```

**I want to display it in the same timezone as the server.**

**Question#2:**

I am using dateTimePicker to pick the time.(Scheduling the report).

How can I pick his localtime (new date()) and convert it to server time? (MomentJS help needed here)

This is my current code:

```
    $datetimepicker.datetimepicker({
        minDate: new Date(),  **//I want to convert this date to server date.**
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        }
    });
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Javascript [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) have methods to deal with UTC/GMT time

Comment: Does [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) do the job?

Comment: _Date.prototype.toUTCString_ would do the trick.

Comment: @JaromandaX But what if the server is NOT in UTC. It might be any timezone.. That's the reason why I get the time in ISO 8601 to understand what timezone it's in!  So that i can convert user time to server time

Comment: @TechnoCorner Do you know the timezone of the server?

Comment: @TechnoCorner `But what if the server is NOT in UTC` - then your statement `My server is in UTC` is a waste of my time (sorry, I just wanted to post a bit of a pun with time - didn't mean to be harsh :p )

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your response. So basically the use case is, I have a box which has got a UTC timezone (Sometimes it can be PST, CST or SGT).. And I have an API to print out the ISO 8601. How can I take user input in another timezone and convert it to server time?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example with local time and UTC]

There are 2 solutions :

### You know what's the timezone of the server

If you know the timezone of the server (the "delta" between the time of the server and the universal time), you can use MomentJS :

```
var time = moment('2017-01-21T00:32:59Z').tz('America/Toronto');
```

### You don't know what is the timezone of the server

In that case, you'd have to make the server send its local time (not the UTC one). Otherwise, you won't be able to guess what's the local time of the server.

Comment: Doesn't ISO 8601 give out timezone info? Can you tell me what do you mean "you'd have to make the server send its local time in ISO." this would be really helpful

Comment: I just mean that the server must send its local time, not the UTC one. Otherwise you won't be able to tell what's the local time of the server.

Comment: @TechnoCorner—if you exchange dates as ISO 8601 with timezone then it doesn't matter what timezone the host is in, '2017-01-21T00:32:59Z' represents the same moment in time regardless of the timezone of the host that is parsing it.

Comment: Excellent Explanation! BRAVO! One question, `you'd have to make the server send its local time` is this different from ISO 8601?

Comment: Thanks! ISO 8601 is just a format that supports time zones, so you should be able to send the local time of your server using ISO 8601.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Date objects contain a UTC time value, so they are UTC by default. The host timezone offset is used for calculations, however in implementations consistent with ECMAScript ed 5 and later (which might not be all that are in use), the string '2017-01-21T00:32:59Z' will be parsed as UTC.

```
new Date('2017-01-21T00:32:59Z')
```

will create a Date object with a time value that is equivalent to '2017-01-21T00:32:59Z'. The time value is actually milliseconds before or after 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, which is why Date objects can be considered to be UTC at heart.

When using the Date *get** methods like *getHours* etc. then the host timezone offset is used to calculate the "local" value, but the Date object itself is still UTC. You can use the *getUTC** methods to see the equivalent UTC values.

When you display a Date, generally its *toString* method is called, which is implementation dependent. However, browsers have sort of standardised the output to be the "local" time based on the host system timezone offset setting.

If you want to see the UTC equivalent, use the *toISOString* method which always uses a +00:00 offset. There is also *toLocaleString*, but it can be very different in different implementations and in Safari at least, my system settings for date and number formats are ignored.

```js
var d = new Date('2017-01-21T00:32:59Z');
console.log('Default:  ' + d.toString());
console.log('ISO 8601: ' + d.toISOString());
console.log('Locale:   ' + d.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Sorry, if I'm sounding really amateurish. This is what I exactly did. But, 

Let's say if i don't know what timezone my box is in, all I have is the ISO 8601. If i want to convert the localtime of my laptop (Let's say PST) to server time (UTC or SGT) .. How would that be possible?

Comment: You don't care about the host timezone. If you exchange dates as ISO 8601 format strings with timezone (typically Z or UTC+00:00) then you only care about timezone when displaying the date, and the standard Date methods take care of that based on the host setting (that you don't care about).